# Javascript logical operator && in statements?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've starting to dig my teeth into backbone and when working with a router function creating and destroying views I came across this little snippet, which didn't quite make sense to me as I've always assumed these sorts of operators only work in conditional statements,

```
this.view && this.view.remove();
```

It was inside of a method attached to the router which seems to work like a charm, but I'm always weary of voodoo code that doesn't sit well with me.

Heres the full method

```
loadView : function(view) {
        this.view && this.view.remove();
        this.view = view;
    }
```

Would love to understand this a bit better, hope its not too silly to ask.

Cheers.

Comment: Have a [look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) at the documentation of javascript logical operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
this.view && this.view.remove();
```

is equivalent to

```
this.view ? this.view.remove() : this.view;
```

The righthand side is only executed if the lefthand side is *truthy*. If the value of the expression is ignored and the lefthand side has no side-effects (as in this case), then it's also equivalent to this:

```
if (this.view) {
    this.view.remove();
}
```

So, in this specific case if there is an existing `view`, then it is removed. Note that the value of this expression is not necessarily a boolean (unlike in many other languages); it's whatever is returned by `remove`. However, this value is ignored, so it's not actually pertinent.

Comment: In other words it is equivalent to: if (this.view) this.view.remove();

Comment: Yep. Was just adding that :)

Comment: if I understand correctly its no different to using the if () {} syntax in effect, so its just shorthand for it, are there any special conditions to whats passed on the left or is it identical ?

Comment: In this case, they're the same. If you wanted to save the result of the expression, then they would no longer be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `&&` in javascript evaluates the first expression, if it is falsy it is returned, if it is truthy the second expression is evaluated and returned.

For `||` it is the other way round: the first expression is evaluated, if it is truthy it is returned, else the second expression is evaluated and returned.

Comment: *"The operator && in javascript returns true when..."* The `&&` doesn't necessarily return true. *"...thus executed if it is a function if the first statement yields the boolean value true."* It doesn't require a  boolean true result from its operand to be considered true.

Comment: @cookie yep I confused it^^.

Comment: okay cool, thanks for the additional info on the 'or', could this be used in variable assignments ? are there any special conditions for its use ?

Comment: yes you can use it like `var foo = bar || baz`, that will assign `bar` to `foo` if it is set and has a truthy value, else it will assign `baz` to `foo`.